# Aligning two flex items: one to the top, the other centered

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

How to achieve this?

[image]

`#top` must be always at the top and fill 100% width of wrapper.

`#center` must be placed in the center - vertically and horizontally.

```
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  height: 400px;
  align-content: center;
}
#top {
  background: #F5A623;
  width: 100%;
}
#center {
  background: #4A90E2;
  align-self: center;
}
```

edit: I've found only solutions that centers div. But I don't know how to place something at the top and something in the center.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perfectly center the `#center` element in the flex container, while having another element at the top, there are two ways you could do this:

1. Introduce a third ("phantom") element to create equal balance, or
2. Absolutely position the `#center` element.

(These same methods could be used to center one item and fix another element to the bottom.)

---

It would be easy to center the `#center` element if it were the *only* flex item in the container. Either of the following two methods would suffice:

```
#wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

OR

```
#center {
    margin: auto;
}
```

***Except*** there is a second flex item in the container occupying space at the top. This means that the centering methods above – which are based on the distribution of *free space* in the container – won't be precise. They will center the `#center` element inside the remaining space, but not inside the entire space (because `#top` is occupying space which, as a result, is excluded from the calculation).

In the following demo, `#center` is perfectly centered in the gray area, but not in the entire flex container, which includes the orange area:

[**DEMO 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/yh15tfqa/)

The `#center` element looks centered, and that may be enough for your purposes, but it's not precisely centered. It's off vertically by 50px, which is the height of the `#top` element.

So another centering method must be used that takes the `#top` space into consideration.

---

#### Method #1: Introduce a third "phantom" element for equal balance

This method involves creating a third flex item with the same height as `#top`. We place this new item on the other side of `#center` to create an equal balance of space on both sides. We then hide this item with `visibility: hidden`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div><!-- invisible flex item -->
</div>
```

**CSS** (relevant section)

```
#top {
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}

#center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#bottom {
    flex: 0 1 50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now `#center` is perfectly centered in the flex container.

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/yh15tfqa/1/)

---

#### Method #2: Absolutely position the `#center` element

Flexbox allows for the [absolute positioning of flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items). This means we could remove `#center` from the document flow and position it relative to its parent.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (relevant sections)

```
#wrap {
    position: relative;
}

#center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Although this method doesn't require an extra flex item (like in Method #1) – and still achieves perfect centering – by removing this item from the document flow it can overlap other elements.

[**DEMO 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/yh15tfqa/2/)

Comment: You could also set position absolute on the top element (just to give all the poosibilities)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one extra element in your HTML which will basically fill the space after the header. Then your content can be centered within that filled space.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: flex-wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#centered {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  align-self: center;
}

#header {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">This is footer content.
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="centered">
      This is centered content.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```