# Vertical align on full height page using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create simple page that has header with navbar that is separated by content area. I am unable to force div `#cover` to be aligned in center vertically. I want my design to be responsive so I do not want to specify width on the parent div `content`.
I know I can use `flex: 1` to fill the rest of the area but I tried that and it does not work for me.

Please see here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMNjyd)

```css
.site-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-content">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="title">TitLe</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="cover">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning two flex items: one to the top, the other centered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246718/aligning-two-flex-items-one-to-the-top-the-other-centered)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the `height` for `.site-content`.

```
.site-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /*new*/
}
```

Or set the percentage height on `html`, `body` and `.site-content` tags.

```
html, body, .site-content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also reset the default margin on `body` as needed.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

To vertically center `#cover`, use `align-items` on the container.

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center; /*new*/
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxPvRR)**