# full-bleed flexbox header with nested nav -- absolute positioning bad practice?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I am making making a full-bleed cover where I want 100% of the viewport on load to have an image, and then I want the header text to be centered.

I used flexbox to do this, the problem is, I also want the navbar in the full-bleed.

I get whitespace when I nest the nav in the header, but if I keep it in, I can't use flex-box to position my header

My last solution was to use absolute positioning and move it over a bit.. which is probably bad practice. I can't come up with a solution on my own other than these -- and I think absolute positioning is bad practice.

I made a codepen with a snippet. and below is my regular code.

I hope this is enough information - the idea is I want my nav inside the full bleed without it disrupting. The current codepen has absolute positioning but I would rather not use that. -- Did I miss something simple or is this a common problem?

I am not opposed to not using flexbox (I just started to use this) But I think there is a solution with flexbox that I am just not aware. Also I know my nav in generally is a little hacky

Here is my codepen and snippet
http://codepen.io/willcodes/pen/oLKZEL

```
HTML:

<nav>
            <div class="nav-left">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-right">
                <li><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>ENG</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <header>
        <div class="heading">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Trendy, Versatile, Minimal Solution to Style up Your Business</h2>
                <h1>Designer. Photographer. Developer.</h1>
                <button class="info">More Info</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/902375b958.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.nav-left {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  position:absolute;
  left:5%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
  padding-top: 1%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul.nav-right {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
      -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
          justify-content: space-around;
}

nav ul.nav-right i.fa-globe {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

nav ul.nav-right li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("../Images/hero.jpg") no-repeat center, black;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

.heading h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Damion", cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.heading h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Possibly guidance [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35246718/3597276). If not, there are more options [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)...

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with using absolute positioning in a flex container *from a technical perspective*. If you're okay with the element being removed from the normal flow, then go ahead. [Absolute positioning is part of the flexbox spec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

Comment: I just feel like doing it with a nav is not really intuitive in a good layout.. and I also think my question should be more common! Going to check out those links though man

Comment: Yeah the two links on SO aren't that helpful, I know how to align and center.. more has to do with getting the nav inside of the header. The W3 doc though might have something I can use I hope :O

Comment: Maybe you can post a demo or image with your desired layout. The code and demo you posted didn't have images and wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: Basically, in my demo, the nav is absolutely positioned inside of the header. If you nest it, or otherwise get it in there, the layout doesn't work. -- The w3 article helped me make my nav cleaner actually :D, I don't have internet at my apartment yet and I'm over on my data so I can't post pictures until I get to a starbucks tomorrow, but I will revise accordingly. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: -- Actually I totally solved it. I had extra margin from the header element which was creating the space -- tomorrow I will post or maybe remove the question haha.

Comment: That whitespace you mentioned wasn't in your code or demo here.