# Add element to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I centered 2 `divs` using `flex`, and I want to add a third `div` to the bottom of the page. Just like the image below

[image]

(I don't want the first 2 `divs` to move up because the third `div`. I want the first 2 `divs` to be centered based on its parent.)

I tried doing it, but the third `div` gets pushed off screen. And I can't make `#centerWrapper's height` less than `100%`, because then the 2 `divs` won't be centered on the full page.

#### JSFiddle

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#centerWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#centerWrapper * {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#firstChild {
  background-color: brown;
}
#secondChild {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#thirdChild {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="centerWrapper">
    <div id="firstChild"></div>
    <div id="secondChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdChild"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a width and height to your third child ? In your example, this element has no width, no height and no content so we can't see it. If you give it a width and height, we can see it but we have to scroll.

Comment: #thirdChild's height is 0px in your code.

Comment: @ZloyPotroh I just realize that now.

Comment: @SylvainB I just realize that now.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35246718/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use position: absolute on thirdChild? Like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7qa7cd20/1/

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#centerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#centerWrapper * {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#firstChild {
    background-color: brown;
}

#secondChild {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#thirdChild {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="centerWrapper">
        <div id="firstChild"></div>
        <div id="secondChild"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdChild"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why doesn't `margin:auto` horizontally center the third `div`? (Instead of `left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);`)

Comment: Oh. oops. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

To keep both blocks at such specified positions would not need the flexibility of flexbox. `position` might be a better solution. Add this ruleset to the `#centerWrapper`:

```
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

For `#thirdChild`, add these styles in order to keep it at the bottom of viewport.

```
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
```

Make `#parent` a flex container of `#centerWrapper` and `#thirdChild`.

#### SNIPPET

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
#centerWrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#centerWrapper * {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
#firstChild {
  background-color: brown;
}
#secondChild {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#thirdChild {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="centerWrapper">
    <div id="firstChild"></div>
    <div id="secondChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdChild"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this, is that the first two `divs` are pushed higher than it should be because of the third `div`. Meaning, if the third `div` wouldn't exist, the first 2 would be lower. I don't want it like that. I want the first two to be centered on the page, and the third one, on the bottom

Comment: Ok, I see, you probably don't need flexbox, `position` is a possibility or a combination of flexbox and `position` (more `position` than flexbox I suspect). Please review the update.

Answer (score 0):

Your #thirdchild doesn't have any height or width. As to get it centered all you need to to do is add `margin: auto;`
I have also made the div 100x100 to make it visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/7qa7cd20/4/

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#centerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#centerWrapper * {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#firstChild {
    background-color: brown;
}

#secondChild {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#thirdChild {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="centerWrapper">
        <div id="firstChild"></div>
        <div id="secondChild"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdChild"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want the third `div` to be visible on the page. Just like the image shows

Comment: For that you can just cut the height of the contentwrapper. Code updated.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this, is that the first two divs are pushed higher than it should be because of the third div. Meaning, if the third div wouldn't exist, the first 2 would be lower. I don't want it like that. I want the first two to be centered on the page, and the third one, on the bottom

Comment: So you want the `thirdchild` div to act as a footer and not require scrolling to see it? For that you have to position it absolutely. Code updated. ------Just know that if the page is too small and the content needs more space, it will be partly hidden by the footer.